# Si actualizo el setup_fee en un plan de una subscripción, se le cobra al usuario nuevamente ese monto?

Tags: mercadopago

Quiero poder hacer cambios entre planes sin que el usuario ingrese una tarjeta.

Si se cambian de plan antes de que expire tengo que cobrarles una diferencia. 
Para esto utilizo el setup_fee. Si actualizo un plan para cambiarles el transaction_amount y setup_fee, esto se cobraría?

Gracias!

Comment: Los cobros de las suscripciones se realizan por adelantado al momento de realizar la suscripción no al mes de vencimiento.

Comment: El setup_fee se cobra unicamente al suscribir un customer a un plan, para asegurarse que el medio de pago es valido.

Comment: Yo no pude hacer funcionar el "setup_fee", vos pudiste? Ni siquiera en la suscripcion original

Answer (score 1):

En MercadoPago las suscripciones se realizan desde customers registrados, estos deben tener un medio de pago por default el cual se usara para acreditar la suscripción.

Si ya tienes subscrito un customer a un plan, cancelas este y lo suscribes a uno nuevo el cual tiene un setup_fee, este es cobrado ya que el fin de esto es asegurarse de que el medio de pago por defecto del customer que se intenta suscribir es valido.

Para mas informacion sobre suscripciones con mercado pago puedes revisar: https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/custom-checkout/plans-and-subscriptions/